# Algolia Wordpress plugin without Instantsearch.js - filtering results by taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, algolia

The Algolia Wordpress plugin (https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/) replaces the standard Wordpress search.

I've selected the *Use Algolia in the backend* setting instead of *Use Algolia with Instantsearch.js*, because I need complete control over the UI.

[image: Algolia setting in Wordpress]

This option states that it does not support filtering and displaying instant search results. However, I'm assuming this is referring to Instantsearch.js and there is still a way to filter the API query manually.

I need to either:

1. Filter the Algolia API search results by taxonomy, likely with facets. Can I customise the query
   that is sent to the Algolia API to include facet filtering?
2. If that's not possible, is there a plugin [filter](https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/filters.html) that would allow me to filter the
   results (and adjust the global WP_Query) after the API query has
   completed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter hook that can be used to adjust the parameters used for the call to Algolia: `algolia_search_params`.

This filter is called right before doing the search operation: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/blob/master/includes/class-algolia-search.php#L59

By using that filter you can provide any valid [Algolia search parameter](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/).